# Hover Image follow mouse on move

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, pseudo-element

I am trying to move a hover image with the mouse.

I have found lots of resources but as I am using a Wordpress theme, I cannot edit the HTML and thus are trying to use pseudo-elements (though it doesn't have to be) to display the image on hover. Is it possible to move a pseudo-element on mouse move?

Otherwise is there JS that I could use to add an image that moves with the mouse on hover?

I am already using some JS to change the background color of the whole section on hover, so perhaps I could hook into that?

This is the URL with the accordion of 'toolkits' where you can see my little pseudo thumbnail, though I want it to appear right next to the mouse and move with it until such time as a user has left the panel.

My js for switching colours if it helps is:

```
$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:first-child").mouseover(function(){
  $(".colour-switching-section").addClass("colour-switch-1");
});


$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:first-child").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".colour-switching-section").removeClass("colour-switch-1");
});
```

And my CSS

```
.colour-switch-1 {
        background-color: #6B9FD5 !important;
        transition: background-color ease-in-out .2s;
    }


    .colour-switch-1::before {
        content: "";
        width: 100px;
        background-image: url('https://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Contact.png');
        background-size: cover;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so in the end I got this to work perfectly - though if there is a slicker solution, that would be great.

HTML

```
<div class="hover-image">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hover-image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 170px;
    background-size: cover;
}


.hover-image.appear-1 {
    background-image:url('image-url');
}

.hover-image.appear-2 {
    background-image:url('image-url');
}

.hover-image.appear-3 {
    background-image:url('image-url');
}
```

JS

```
$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:first-child").mouseover(function(){
  $(".hover-image").addClass("appear-1");
});


$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:first-child").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".hover-image").removeClass("appear-1");
});

$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:nth-child(2)").mouseover(function(){
  $(".hover-image").addClass("appear-2");
});


$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:nth-child(2)").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".hover-image").removeClass("appear-2");
});

$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:nth-child(3)").mouseover(function(){
  $(".hover-image").addClass("appear-3");
});


$(".colour-switching-section .panel-group .panel:nth-child(3)").mouseleave(function(){
  $(".hover-image").removeClass("appear-3");
});
```